# Could anybody recommend me some games for my kid in ubuntu?

Tags: games

I have installed tuxpaint, supertuxkart but would like to know which games are good for my kid who is 3 years old and likes to play games in computer very much.

Thank you.

Comment: any type of game which is suitable for 3 years old kid

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely **solicit opinion**, debate, arguments, **polling**, or extended discussion.

Answer (score 9):

> **Ri-Li**
>
> Ri-li is an arcade game licensed under the GPL (General Public License). You drive a toy wood engine in many levels and you must collect all the coaches to win.You can download it and play indefinitely. It's Free. You can play on 'Linux', 'Mac OsX', 'Windows', 'AmigaOS4'

[image]

1 small snag: there is no Ubuntu package for it so [download](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ri-li/Ri-li-2.0.1-1.i586.rpm?download) the rpm package and convert using alien:

```
sudo alien - d -c Ri-li-2.0.0-1.i586.rpm
```

Also have a look at the [gcompris](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gcompris) [image: Install gcompris] package.

> GCompris is a large collection of educational games for small children (2-10). It is designed to be a unified interface to integrate more educational games.

Currently available boards include: learning how to use a mouse and keyboard, learning simple arithmetic, learning how to read an analog clock, recognize letters after hearing their names, reading practice, small games (memory games, jigsaw puzzles, ...).

Screenshots: http://gcompris.net/screenshots-en.html

Answer (score 8):

Here's a short list of some games that  can find in your ubuntu software centre

.
[**Potato Guy/KTuberling**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/ktuberling/)

[image: screen]

Potato Guy/KTuberling
KTuberling is a drawing game designed for small children. It is essentially an editor wherein the child can drag and paste eyes, ears etc onto the picture of a guy shaped as a potato. The game can also spell out the names of the objects that we drag and place on the screen. It will speak in the language that you choose. This will help you to develop your vocabulary in any foreign language. In addition to the potato guy, you can create other themes like building a town. The game does not have a winner and is played for fun.

[**GCompris**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/gcompris/)

[image]
GCompris
GCompris is a collection of games created for children aged 2-10. The full version of the software is available for free on Ubuntu. You can start a game by simply clicking on the appropriate icon on the screen. The games are simple and include reading practice, letter identification and counting numbers. Through appealing graphics and professional soundtracks that accompany every game, you can enhance your numerical and verbal skills along with entertainment.

[**Bouncy The Hungry Rabbit**](http://Bouncy%20The%20Hungry%20Rabbit)

[image]

Bouncy The Hungry Rabbit
This is a simple game where you are the rabbit. You want to eat the tasty vegetables in a garden without the farmer noticing. You can hide behind objects and move around to escape from the farmer. Although the game is designed for kids, adults can also play the game because the ‘hard’ level is truly challenging.

[**Wormux**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/wormux/)

[image]

Wormux
Wormux is a funny game played on a 2D map. The players choose their teams which can be animals like dragons, chickens, bulls etc or even aliens. The teams play with the weapons you choose which may vary from dynamites to baseball bats. The goal of each team is to exterminate the other teams. You win when your team survives and all others are killed. Although the game is being developed further, it is already very much playable.

[**Frozen bubble**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/frozen-bubble/)

[image]

Frozen bubble
In this game, you shoot balls into another set of balls and when the adjacent shot balls are of the same color, they fall and you score. You win when the top wall is devoid of balls. This is a game of speed because if you do not hurry, the top wall will automatically push the balls down which then strike the launcher and you lose.

look [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-114380.html) also